# Why the value is not changed on apply method of a companion object?

Tags: scala

I've created a class with a companion object and i want to "change" a parameter of the method `apply` but when I instantiate a new object the value keeps the original value

```
case class Product(name: String, stock: Int)
object Product {
    def apply(name: String, stock: Int): Product = new Product(name, stock + 1)
}

val product = new Product("t-shirt", 0)
println(product) // ("t-shirt", 0)
```

Why the product stock still `0` if I add `+1` on the `apply` method?

Here is the code running: https://glot.io/snippets/fwr951ugrs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you remain calling object constructor via `new` and not `apply` from companion object. You want to do next:

```
val product = Product("t-shirt", 0) // here `apply` invoked implicitly from `Product` companion object
println(product) // ("t-shirt", 1)
```

Full Scatie example: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ENOSuVmJSASQ7odPRlOd3g

Comment: Also, it may be good to make the constructor `private` to avoid someone by-passing such logic.